# Where can I store my recommendation materials

Tags: php, system, recommendation-engine

I created an e-learning system and based on the lowest score of the pre-assessments of that topic I want  the system recommend her/him a learning materials. Where can I store the learning materials that will recommend?

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve it:

## Creating a file for each learning material

If you do not have too many learning materials and you do not need to frequently manage them, then it is feasible to create a PHP file for each learning material, generating a partial HTML, like a `<div>` wrapped around the learning material to be shown.

## Creating a single file with multiple templates

You can create a single file which could be used to retreive all learning materials, or a part of them, you can have HTML as it is or functions returning textual templates. You may decide to serve POST requests of already loaded pages to fill it with learning materials, or you could generate the content before the page is initially loaded.

## Storing the learning materials in a database

You could use a relational database, like MySQL or a NoSQL database, like Redis to store the learning materials. This makes a lot of sense if you have many learning materials to manage. However, if you have multimedia content, like videos or so, then it would make sense to store the actual files as files in a folder dedicated to them and their metadata in a database, while their wrapper structure in code files.